# Iterator implementation issues

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I wrote the following code when trying to make a doubly-linked list with an internal STL-like iterator.  I'll just provide the header file with the non-relevant parts trimmed out for now.

My questions are...

1. The STL uses iterators in a certain way - specifically, you navigate over an STL container from the .begin() iterator up to but not including the .end() iterator.  To do this the .end() iterator has to be one-past the end of the container.  How would I implement this kind of semantic given what I've started with (this is the main question)?
2. Is there anything missing in the interface as it stands (with regard to the iterator class and things that should be present in it)?

Here's the code:

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T>* next;
    Node<T>* prev;
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    public:

        class Iterator
        {
            public:

                Iterator() {}
                explicit Iterator(const Node<T>& init) { current = init; }

                //Dereference operator - return the current node's data.
                inline T& operator*() { return current->data; }

                //Prefix returns by reference.
                inline Iterator& operator++()   { current = current->next; return *this; } 
                inline Iterator& operator--()   { current = current->prev; return *this; }

                //Postfix returns non-reference and has int parameter to differentiate function signature.
                inline Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator res = *this; current = current->next; return res; }
                inline Iterator operator--(int) { Iterator res = *this; current = current->prev; return res; }

            private:

                Node<T>* current;
        };

        Iterator begin() { return Iterator(m_start); }
        Iterator end()   { return Iterator(m_end);   }

    private:
        Node<T>* m_start;
        Node<T>* m_end;
};
```

I'm aware that I may or may not have problems with the ++/-- operators, but that doesn't particularly bother me as I'll work those out when I have enough code to do some testing on this.  Feel free to drop hints though if you're inclined :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First node's prev pointer is NULL, so is last node's next pointer. One-past-the-end's `current` pointer would be NULL.
2. `operator->`

Comment: How would I implement that operator -> for the needs of this class? (I'm not asking specifically how the operator is overloaded, more like what would I make it do, I don't know how to forward it to call a function from the underlying list data type).  and thank you for the answer so far :) +1

Comment: @w00te It just returns a pointer to the data `&current->data`, strange but it's the way it works. Though some information in the answer would be nice.

Comment: @w00te `T* operator ->() { return &(current->data); }`

Comment: Oh thank you, beat me too the more detailed comment, haha.  So, that'll make it work like an STL iterator? strange, seems like there should be more to it.  I guess that's what Rau means :)

Comment: If one-past-end's `current` is NULL, then how would `--list.end();` work?

Answer (score 2):

1. The iterator returned by `end()` must be decrementable, otherwise you cannot iterate over the list in reverse.
   You could do this, by having Iterator store two pointers: to current node (which would be NULL for end) and to previous node (which allows you to find the last node with data in it, even if `current == NULL`.

   ```
   class Iterator
   {
       public:

           Iterator() {}
           explicit Iterator(Node<T>* curr, Node<T>* prev):
               current(curr), previous(prev) {}

           //Dereference operator - return the current node's data.
           inline T& operator*() { return current->data; }

           //Prefix returns by reference.
           inline Iterator& operator++()   
           { 
               previous = current;
               current = current->next; 
               return *this; 
           } 
           inline Iterator& operator--()   
           { 
               current = previous; 
               previous = current->previous;
               return *this; 
           }

           //Postfix should be implemented in terms of prefix operators
           inline Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator res = *this; ++*this; return res; }
           inline Iterator operator--(int) { Iterator res = *this; --*this; return res; }

       private:

           Node<T>* current;
           Node<T>* previous;
   };

   Iterator begin() { return Iterator(m_start, 0); }
   Iterator end()   { return Iterator(0, m_end);   }
   ```

   Alternatively you can have your list contain a sentinel node that designates the "one-past-end" of the list. This node should not have the data member though. This can be achieved by splitting the Node class into a non-template base with only pointers to next and previous node.

   For example, it appears that GCC's list implementation stores a pointer to the sentinel, so that its `next` points to the first item in the list and its `prev` points to the last item in the list (or both point to itself, if the list is empty).
2. You are missing `operator->`, `operator==` and `operator!=`, the classification typedefs which can be inherited from [std::iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator/), a const_iterator implementation (iterator should be implicitly convertible to const_iterator).

Answer (score 1):

1. I think NULL will fit here just great.
2. You may want to write something like `for (iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++)`, so you need comparison operators to be defined too.

Comment: Of course the comparison operators, completely forgot about those. But to `+` and the like, a double linked list actually has only bidirectional iterators. Although you could hide that by implementing a loop in `+=`, it would hide the linear complexity of this operation, therefore I would stay with bidirectional iterators and not include `+=` and co. That's what the explicit `std::advance` is for.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yeah, maybe operators like `+` are unnecessary here. I really didn't think this through.